# curl request with environment variable works but fails on python3 requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, curl, python-requests

I am trying to convert this **working** curl command:

```
curl ipinfo.io/8.8.8.8/json?token=$TOKEN
```

to python3 requests. This is my current script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import requests

def getIPInfo ():
    params = (
    ('token', '$TOKEN'),
    )

    response = requests.get('http://ipinfo.io/8.8.8.8/json', params=params)
    
    print(response)

getIPInfo()
```

However, when I run it, I get back "Error 403"?

```
<Response [403]>
```

Comment: Because you are passing literally `"$TOKEN"` as the token.

Comment: `$TOKEN` in the command line is a variable, not a literal string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$TOKEN` part of your cURL command actually pulls a value from the environment. You need to use [`os.environ`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ) to accomplish the same thing in Python.

Also, I would use a `dict` for the `params` as it's a bit more clear than the tuple of tuples.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import requests
import os

def getIPInfo ():
    params = {
        'token': os.environ.get('TOKEN'),
    }

    response = requests.get('http://ipinfo.io/8.8.8.8/json', params=params)
    
    print(response)

getIPInfo()
```

Comment: Absolutely makes sense, and it's working :)

Answer (score 1):

> Why do I get back "Error 403"?

Because you are passing literally `"$TOKEN"` as the token. Instead, you need to pass in a valid auth token.